# PIC 10F200 MCLR PIN as Output

Tags: pic, embedded, microchip, system, pickit

I need To use MCLR pin to make led blinking 
using this configuration but I conn't write the code for that

[image]

Comment: So, what is your plan to enable you to write the code and, more importantly for this site, do you have an actual question related to electrical/electronics engineering?

Comment: It's [in the article](https://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4325428/Use-the-MCLR-pin-as-an-output-with-PIC-microcontrollers). "To allow the GP3/MCLR pin to act as an output, the circuit uses the configurable weak pullups that this microcontroller offers."

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet from the 10F200 manual. Note the arrows on the GPIO pins. The one for GP3/MCLR points only inwards because it is an input-only pin.

[image]

In a comment Renan mentions that the weak pull-up feature could be used to create a weak open-source-type output, apparently your circuit is designed for that mode of use. The GPWU bit in the option register (set by the OPTION instruction) controls the weak pull-ups.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to disable the MCLRE function on the pin first (otherwise the chip auto-resets when you disable the GPPU). The WPUA current range is 50/250/400uA min/typ/max.  You would have to add an external pulldown resistor, otherwise the gate would float once you disable the GPPU.  To keep the Vgs high enough (~5V) you'd need a minimum pulldown resistor value of ~100K.  Note I've had problems getting PICs to recognize programmers once the MCLRE pin is disabled in such a manner (it may require a high voltage programming mode).

Comment: The circuit the OP shows has a 1 M pull-down resistor. And yes, once you disable the MCLR function you generally need HVP to re-program.

Comment: @Oojien. Sorry about that, when inspecting the schematic last night it I honestly didn't see that part.  Only possible issue with a 1M value is you get into leakage current territory with the MCLR pin datasheet has a higher leakage value for that pin which could actually turn on some of the high efficiency LEDs (I have some that are quite bright at <1mA current).

Comment: You won't catch me saying this approach is a good one...